# how to filter with array/list via dynamic linq

Tags: .net, dynamic-linq

Hell all!

I tried all known variations to filter with `Contains`, but so far no luck.

METHOD #1

```
ret = ret.Where("CaseID.Contains(@0)", {15, 16, 17})
```

Gets the following error:

> System.Linq.Dynamic.ParseException: 'No applicable method 'Contains' exists in type 'Int32?''

METHOD #2

```
ret.Where("@0.Contains(outerIt.CaseID)", {15, 16, 17})
```

Bring the following error:

> System.Linq.Dynamic.ParseException: 'No 'it' is in scope'

So, how can i filter by a list or array?

I'm using the latest System.Linq.Dynamic library in nuget 1.0.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the following will work, but you must to ensure that the `CaseID` and the array values have the same Type.

`ret.Where("@0.Any(outerIt.CaseID=it)", array)`

Comment: This still gives me the error `System.Linq.Dynamic.ParseException: 'No 'it' is in scope'`

Comment: try to replace the array parameter with a list

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if I understand your question right.
But do you mean something like this?
This is solved with a Lambda-Expression.

```
var listA = new[] {1, 2, 3, 5, 8};
var listB = new[] {1, 3, 5, 7, 11};
var res = listA.Where(itemA => listB.Contains(itemA));
// res = {1,3,5}
```